# IoT device sends information as telemetry and twins. What is the difference between then which has to be when?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I have a confusion here, IoT devices sends data in the form of telemetry and the same would be done through configuring device twins(might be I am wrong. But as I don't have clarity over this I am asking questions). Then, in what scenarios do we prefer to use configuring device twins over sending telemetry.

Answer (score 0):

Telemetry and device twins are quite different things.

Generally, when talking about telemetry we are talking about the data your device sends, like temperature or humidity. Device twins are JSON documents that store device state information including metadata, configurations, and conditions ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins)).

You see the difference? Device twins can, for example, be used to configure the telemetry reporting interval.

Comment: In addition, the device telemetry data flows to the data stream pipeline in opposite to the device twins, where they are persisted in the backend as a non-telemetry data (states). In other words, the telemetry data using a streaming endpoint (path).